# Schedule function execution in swift

Tags: swift, dispatch-async

I'm developing a simple app in Swift and I need to schedule a function execution every 24 hours. I'm aware of the method:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
    self.functionToCall()
})
```

that could solve my problem but, is this the right solution for a 24 hours delay?
Thanks

Comment: In iOS this is only possible for an App, which is running constantly in the foreground. On macOS you should better use a cronjob or background service. What do want to achieve with this function?

Comment: It Is a macos app that runs on the status bar. I want the function to check if some brew formulae need to be updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theoretically, this is possible. 
The problem is that your app would have to run in the foreground for 24 hours, which is very unlikely to happen. Unfortunately, you can not run background tasks just like that.

**The solution:**

Just make it look like the function would execute in the background. Every time the update function is called, simply save the `Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)` to UserDefaults. This works like a timestamp and saves the last time you called your update function. Every time in the viewDidLoad()-function (not sure if it's called the same on Mac apps, but you can imagine what I mean) call:

```
If let timestamp = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "yourTimestampKey") {

   let currentTimestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
   if (currentTimestamp - timestamp) > 86400 { // number of seconds in 24 hours 
      // the last time your function was updated was at least 24h ago

      update()
   }

}
```

That's how you can make it appear like it was updated in the background. I use this all the time in my apps and it works perfectly.

EDIT:

Maybe, just in case the app does indeed run 24 hours in a row, I would set up the upper function that you posted first as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, probably I had to explain better how my app works right now: the update function is called every time the application is launched hence, i don't mind to call the function exactly every 24 hours. My problem is, supposing that the user does not switch off the Mac in 24 h, i want that the update is scheduled 24 hours after the last time the app checked. So, do you think that the dispatch after will work properly? Edit: the app remains active in the status bar, it's like the dropbox or google drive apps.

Comment: Yes, it will definitely work then. Good luck :) @MarcoMaggipinto